# Open With "program" is empty

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

When I try to open my file extension with a right click on the file and open with..., my program does not display its name and is just an empty string along with the icon. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set all of the fields in `Properties`, `Assembly Information...`.  (also found in `AssemblyInfo.cs`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft Knowledge Base article on "[How To Associate a File Extension with Your Application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185453/EN-US)".

Although this is for Win32 applications, you could rather simple use it as a base for your C# implementation, in my opinion. [Here is a code snippet](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid694A842E0DFE8CFB00BF8E70DC4AA1F2CBFCAE3B.aspx) I wrote some time back.

The basic think you need is the following registry hierarchy (quoted from the KB article):

```
.bar = MyApp
     MyApp = My Application
       |
        -- Shell
             |
              -- open
                   |
                    -- command = c:\mydir\my.exe %1
```